# "The system cannot find the specified file" when I launch visual studio build tools 2022(2), how to fix it?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]
[image: Visual Studio Installer]

---

** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.8.0
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation

---

系统找不到指定的文件。

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools>